# How to deploy SharePoint Service Application during development

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, service

I am currently developing a SharePoint Service Application. I need to deploy it very frequently to test the newly updated code. For this, I am using 'Deploy' command available in Visual Studio 2010. Service application gets deployed successfully, but the new code update is NOT up and running until I restart my entire machine. I tried to restart IIS Admin Service. No Use. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*[Answer was posted by the OP in a comment]*

Actually, the service application has been hosted in a separate application pool. Once I recycle that particular application pool, the newly modified code gets affected and running. It helps me to avoid computer restart and IIS reset.